# Rails, Heroku - transfer db data between environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have 3 environments: development (local), staging (heroku) and production (heroku).

I would like the ability to transfer specific db data from one environment to another. This data might be one record, two records, a table, or several tables.

I thought of combining such workflow with the [seed_dump gem](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) but what could be the steps to "push/pull" data from one environment to the other?

Can I do it with the command line / rake tasks / console / something else?

Which commands should I use?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `heroku run rake db:seed:dump` to generate **db/seeds.rb** in staging env, then you need to move the file to production branch, and just run `heroku run rake db:seed` in production env?

Comment: @majioa How can I move the file from staging to production?

Comment: if you use the branch model in your git, just merge/add the file into the production branch